# Trying to install RocketChat on AWS, made some mistake

Tags: docker, rocket.chat

**docker config** as the site ask us to do.

```
 services:
   rocketchat:
     image: rocket.chat:latest
     command: >
       bash -c
         "for i in `seq 1 30`; do
           node main.js &&
           s=$$? && break || s=$$?;
           echo \"Tried $$i times. Waiting 5 secs...\";
           sleep 5;
         done; (exit $$s)"
     restart: unless-stopped
     volumes:
       - ./uploads:/app/uploads
     environment:
       - PORT=3000
       - ROOT_URL=https://muradempreendimentos.com
       - MONGO_URL=mongodb://mongo:27017/rocketchat
       - MONGO_OPLOG_URL=mongodb://mongo:27017/local
     depends_on:
       - mongo
     ports:
       - 3000:3000

   mongo:
     image: mongo:4.0
     restart: unless-stopped
     command: mongod --smallfiles --oplogSize 128 --replSet rs0 --storageEngine=mmapv1
     volumes:
       - ./data/runtime/db:/data/db
       - ./data/dump:/dump

   # this container's job is just to run the command to initialize the replica set.
   # it will run the command and remove himself (it will not stay running)
   mongo-init-replica:
     image: mongo:4.0
     command: >
       bash -c
         "for i in `seq 1 30`; do
           mongo mongo/rocketchat --eval \"
             rs.initiate({
               _id: 'rs0',
               members: [ { _id: 0, host: 'localhost:27017' } ]})\" &&
           s=$$? && break || s=$$?;
           echo \"Tried $$i times. Waiting 5 secs...\";
           sleep 5;
         done; (exit $$s)"
     depends_on:
     - mongo
```

**output** after running the command "sudo docker-compose logs -f rocketchat"

```
ERROR: yaml.parser.ParserError: while parsing a block mapping
  in "./docker-compose.yml", line 1, column 1
expected <block end>, but found <block mapping start>
  in "./docker-compose.yml", line 3, column 2
```

What can I try next to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I **copied and pasted** your file and attempted to setup the `rocketchat`. The only issue I found was the lack of `version`. From [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/):

> Compose files using the version 2 syntax **must indicate the version number** at the root of the document.

After adding `version: '2'` at the top of the file, I had no problems setting up `mongo` and `rocketchat` using your file.

Also had no issues with yaml formatting. The format of the file you have is correct yaml.

Comment: @PabloMurad What you've posted does not have any version. Maybe you've posted wrong file?

Comment: I forgot to put here that I already put the version, but it keeps: ERROR: yaml.parser.ParserError: while parsing a block mapping
  in "./docker-compose.yml", line 1, column 1
expected <block end>, but found '<block mapping start>'
  in "./docker-compose.yml", line 3, column 2

Comment: I follow the documentation as a priest follow the bible lol and im still stucked

Comment: @PabloMurad I don't know. The only issue in my test was the version missing when I used your `docker-compose.yml`.

Comment: I used visual code to debug, it appoints an error at line 2 and 19 andddd i didnt get it btw

Comment: can be another thing you did in the past and i missed? i dont think so, it's so basical.

Comment: @PabloMurad I used command line in linux. Could be editor based issue?

Comment: i used in the begin, but now im trying visual to debug. well, can you send to me your  yaml? and i try here

Comment: SOLVED. It was a space problem. :(

Comment: @PabloMurad No problem. Glad it got sorted out.